# Running Vsts agent on nano server

Tags: docker, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, windows-server-2016

I am looking to run vsts agent on docker image with nano server on it. The container already has .Net Core installed on it. I downloaded vsts agent using the Download Agent and config.cmd command. Got the following error

```
An error occurred while sending the request. Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

Here are the details

Windows Version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

.Net Core Version  : 1.0.1
.Net Core Build    : cee57bf6c981237d80aa1631cfe83cb9ba329f12

Looking at Diagnostics log, I get the following error

> [2016-10-18 07:29:46Z ERR  Terminal] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The parameter is incorrect
>      at System.Net.Http.WinHttpAuthHelper.SetWinHttpCredential(SafeWinHttpHandle requestHandle, ICredentials credentials, Uri uri, UInt32 authScheme, UInt32 authTarget)
>      at System.Net.Http.WinHttpAuthHelper.CheckResponseForAuthentication(WinHttpRequestState state, UInt32& proxyAuthScheme, UInt32& serverAuthScheme)
>      at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__101.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__42`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.d__41.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.d__7.MoveNext()
>   [2016-10-18 07:29:46Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's the detail value you specified when configure agent? Could you access your TFS or VSTS from that machine?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to VSTS using the same values from my host machine

Comment: What's the detail value you specified when configure agent?

Comment: This is now raised an an issue with the product team

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/483

Comment: From the latest comment from the product team, running vsts agent on Nano server is not supported yet.

"It's likely not just this issue. The Windows build of the agent currently makes an assumption that Full .NET is installed. It has validation checks that verify that .NET >= 4.5 is installed. It sounds like it's missing validation to distinguish between .NET Full and .NET Core.

My understanding is that Nano doesn't have .NET Full, and only has .NET Core. We'll need to take a pass through the agent, given Nano constraints, and figure out what it means for an agent running on Nano."

Comment: From your comment, what's the result after you install dotnet core on Windows Nano?

Comment: It was installed correctly

Comment: So, to conclude, VSTS agent is not supported on Nano server. You can post an answer and mark it after 24 hours.

Comment: thanks @starain . Put the response as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it raised as an issue with the product team. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/483

The scenario is not supported as yet. I.e VSTS agents can't run Windows Nano Server. Following are excerpt from the response the team

"It's likely not just this issue. The Windows build of the agent currently makes an assumption that Full .NET is installed. It has validation checks that verify that .NET >= 4.5 is installed. It sounds like it's missing validation to distinguish between .NET Full and .NET Core.

My understanding is that Nano doesn't have .NET Full, and only has .NET Core. We'll need to take a pass through the agent, given Nano constraints, and figure out what it means for an agent running on Nano."